# Need Oracle Solaris 10 SPARC VM template for VirtualBox

Tags: oracle, virtualbox, solaris-10

I have Windows 7 64 bit as host OS on which I've installed VirtualBox 4.2.16. Now I want to install Solaris 10 SPARC vm inside VirtualBox. Can anyone tell me from where can I download Oracle Solaris 10 SPARC VM template for VirtualBox?

[This page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/vmtemplates-vmvirtualbox-1949721.html) lists only the 64 bit versions.
[This page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/vmtemplates-sparc-x86-1949722.html) lists 'Oracle VM Templates for SPARC' but I'm not sure if these templates are for VirtualBox. Can anyone tell me if that will work or not?

Thanks, 
AndyT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that VirtualBox does emulation. It does only virtualization. You would have to use [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) (or similar software) to emulate SPARC on top of Intel hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use template on virtual box from Oracle.
Or use QEMU for simulation.

Comment: you can download template for virtual box from "http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/downloads/vm-templates-2245495.html"  Oracle Solaris 11.2 VM Template for Oracle VM VirtualBox